# The procedure entry point ... could not be located in the dynamic link library Qt5Core.dll

Tags: windows-7, dll, google-earth

When starting googleearth.exe I get the following popup :

```
googleearth.exe - Entry Point Not Found

"The procedure entry point ?toUpper@QString@@QEGBA?AV1@XZ could not be located in the dynamic link library Qt5Core.dll"
```

This popup opens 3 times in a row, by clicking OK on each, then GoogleEarth starts seemingly without any problem.

Error persists even after GoogleEarth has been uninstalled and reinstalled. All files in target directory is verified deleted, and a new version of qt5core.dll is created on reinstall.

How to proceed on this?

Comment: Questions: (1) Which entry point? (2) Do you have the Qt development package installed separately on the computer? (3) What is the installation folder of GoogleEarth and Qt5Core.dll? (4) Search the entire computer and see if there exist other instances of Qt5Core.dll.

Comment: 1) edited question 2) Don't believe so, but have IDEs like VS, Android Studio, some Python stuff etc. 3) C:\Program Files\Google\Google Earth Pro\client  4) Have 13 Qt5Core.dll's related to variuos software, non that indicates qt-development package though. Btw I think the entry point on this error have been different on earlier GoogleEarth install, so it seems perhaps related to the dll generally and not the entry point.

Answer (score 0):

If `googleearth.exe` and `Qt5Core.dll` are in the same folder, then this is a 
problem with the Google Earth release, which is not serious if everything works
correctly. You may signal it to Microsoft (if a support address is given).

If they are not in the same folder and some other folder containing `Qt5Core.dll`
is in your PATH environmental variable, then you may either:

- Ignore the problem if it has no ill-effects.
- Remove the other folder from PATH (if that doesn't break anything).
- Start `googleearth.exe` through a batch `.bat` script that before doing that
  will put the right folder into the local PATH of the script.